# Jenkins declarative pipeline: How to access value of parameter when it has spaces in its name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to execute one stage of my Jenkins pipeline only if a particular boolean parameter is true. Currently I have this in my declarative Jenkinsfile:

```
booleanParam(
    defaultValue: false, 
    name: 'forceGenerateNuGet'
)
...
when {
    expression { forceGenerateNuGet == "true" }
}
```

This works fine. But the above is ugly since the name shows up in the UI.

I would like to have this (pseudocode):

```
booleanParam(
    defaultValue: false, 
    name: 'Force generate NuGet'
)
...
when {
    expression { getValueOfParam('Force generate NuGet') == "true" }
}
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**: This post at Devops Stack Exchange says that I should be able to use `params['Force generate NuGet']`.

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/in-jenkins-how-can-parameters-that-contain-spaces-be-referenced/4712?newreg=bc037a0b92d94b609be577272600c7fd

That doesn't work for me, though. I tried to apply it and run a build where I set the parameter, but it doesn't pick up the value and hence skips the step it was supposed to execute. :(

If I tell it to output the parameter values, it just tells me they are null.

```
script {
    def force = params["Force generate NuGet"]
    echo "Force generate NuGet: ${force}"
}
```

Output:

```
[2021-02-09T15:13:37.571Z] Force generate NuGet: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It turns out that `params['Force generate NuGet']` actually does work. I had a long Jenkinsfile with some legacy code that *overwrote* the global variable `params`. That is why it was not working for me. I revised the legacy code, and now I can get the parameters.